# Is there a good place to ask questions about the Apptivate.MS contest?

Tags: discussion, meta, apptivate.ms

As I understand Stack Overflow is helping organize the [Apptivate.ms](http://apptivate.ms/) contest. Under Q&A on that site it basically takes Windows 8 development-related tags from SO. But is there a place to ask "meta"-Apptivate.MS questions? Is meta.stackoverflow the right place?

In particular I have the question: "Are we allowed to use Phonegap in part of the application for the contest?"

Comment: Yes. Here. You found us. We even have a tag.

Comment: I am not familiar with phonegap - is it just a compiling service? If you read the [apptivate rules, terms and conditions](http://apptivate.ms/contest#rules-terms-conditions), I don't see it mentioned.

Comment: I don't see it mention either, that's why I had the question, and now I officially asked it ;-) http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/180932/160880

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Meta.SO (serving as the full Stack Exchange meta) is the correct place.

Use the [apptivate.ms](/questions/tagged/apptivate.ms) tag for your question.