# Using Phonegap for the Apptivate.MS contest?

Tags: discussion, apptivate.ms

[Phonegap](http://phonegap.com/) is a commonly-used HTML, CSS, and JavaScript solution for developing cross-platform apps. I was wondering if for the [Apptivate.MS](http://apptivate.ms/) contest we are allowed to port an app that's mostly developed in Phonegap. Obviously, such a port is more trivial than a native-to-native port. I couldn't find anything about Phonegap (or related cross-platform "technologies") in the rules for Apptivate.MS.

**Edit:** I suspect that Oded's answer is exactly correct in terms of how I asked the question (so I marked it as such), meaning that we are probably "allowed" to use Phonegap. But any further comments on whether using Phonegap is "encouraged" or "discouraged". Those are usually the terms judges use to suggest what's more likely to help you win the contest ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not a lawyer, only a dev.

My reading of the contest terms and conditions shows nothing about **how** you port and what tools you use when porting an app.

The major requirements are - have an existing app that has not been ported yet and port it during the competition.

The only restrictions mentioned in the [terms and conditions](http://apptivate.ms/contest#rules-terms-conditions) are:

> **Content Restrictions:**
>
> - The Submission must not contain material that violates or infringes another’s rights, including but not limited to privacy, publicity or intellectual property rights, or that constitutes copyright infringement;
> - The Submission must not contain brand names or trademarks, except for Sponsor's trademark for which entrant has a limited license to use for the sole purposes of creating and uploading a Submission into this Contest;
> - The Submission must not contain images or artwork not created by entrant;
> - The Submission must not contain material that is inappropriate, indecent, obscene hateful, tortious, defamatory, slanderous or libelous;
> - The Submission must not contain material that promotes bigotry, racism, hatred or harm against any group or individual or promotes discrimination based on race, gender, religion, nationality, disability, sexual orientation or age; and
> - The Submission must not contain material that is unlawful, in violation of or contrary to the laws or regulations in any state where the Submission is created.

Nothing about phonegap.

Comment: You are probably right in a "legal" sense, but I wonder if it's something they will look upon favorably or not. It seems that native might be strongly preferred (hopefully not).

Comment: @Lex - I've not gotten any indication to this. It is not something that the judges should be using as criteria, as far as I can see.